# Why is it that logical thinking is bad for emotional connection?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

I notice that after studying mathematics or logic for a long time, I can't speak to people in a fluid manner. Language becomes very functional. What brain areas are involved in this transition? Why?

Comment: You'll probably get more attention/answers if you do a little research on this phenomenon yourself, from either end, and add more information.  Also, I would note that your title assumes that logical thinking is bad for emotional connection, but your question text is more about logical thinking and language function.  Which question are you more interested in?

Comment: Are you looking to find out how the brain transitions from 'logical' to 'emotional' thinking (if it does at all)?

Comment: I actually find the opposite to be true sometimes.